# Static char array not found and not working with strncpy?

Tags: c, string, variables, static, char

```
char *  function decode time()
{ 

   tm *ptm; //time structure
    static char timeString[STRLEN]; //hold string from asctime()

    ptm = gmtime( (const time_t *)&ltime ); //fill in time structure with ltime

    if(ptm) 
    {

       strncpy(timeString, asctime( ptm ), sizeof(timeString) ); 
//EDIT  
sprintf(test, "Sting is: %s", timeString);


       return timeString;
.
.
} //end function
```

When I step through the code in the debugger I I can see the value of timeString is:
timeString CXX0017: Error: symbol "timeString" not found

However, when I remove the work "static" from timeString it does fill in correctly with the string but is now a local copy and will be destroyed.

Why am I not able to copy the string from this function into a static char array?

Visual Studio 6.0  - MFC

Thanks.

**EDIT**
the "test" string does contain the value of timeString.

I guess this is just a debugger issue? but why can't I see the value of a static array in the debugger watch?

Comment: Two things. **1)** What scope is timeString declared in? Is it in the same function as the call to `strncpy`, if it's global is it in the same C file? **2)** What do you mean "When I run the code through the debugger"?

Comment: @torak: 1) all are in the same function. 2) When I step through in the debugger the variable watch value is "Error..not found".

Comment: Is it just that the debugger is confused or is there a real problem?

Comment: Try dropping it from the watch window and adding it once it's in scope.

Comment: @Steven Sudit: Doesn't seem to help. Also when I "hover over" it- it displays nothing.

Comment: There seem to be two possible reasons for it. The first is that since the .o file doesn't need a symbol entry for static variables the .pdb file doesn't get a symbol entry for it. The second is that some kind of name mangling occurs so that you can declare `static int foo;` in multiple functions without name collision. Eitherway dumping the contents of the .pdb file might prove enlightening. If I remember correctly DiaDump is a sample program in the DIA SDK that should do the trick.

Comment: According to this guy I am a terrible programmer? http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/36195258/debugging-static-variables-in-vc6.aspx   but looks like someone had the same issue as me.

Comment: @torak: Visual Studio isn't a Unix compiler, so no `.o` files. But you're right that local variables don't need their symbols published. However, that doesn't explain why they can see the variable when it's not declared as `static`.

Comment: Found this, however, my static variable is not a class member... "Can't View Data When Watching or Quick Watching a Static Data Variable" : http://support.microsoft.com/kb/121367

Comment: @Steven Sudit: Yes true, it should be .obj no .o. However, the OP says that the problem goes away when he removes the static declaration.

Comment: @Tommy: I think that explains it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, function name should be
`function_decode_time()` not `function decode time()`

with local static timeString will initialized entire with '\0', without static its not guaranteed
without static you the return value in calling context is undefined.

strncpy will not added a '\0' in timeString for use "sizeof(timeString)" , see definition;
therefore YOU must added '\0', eg:

```
char * functionDecodeTime()
{
  tm *ptm; /* time structure */
  static char timeString[STRLEN]; /* hold string from asctime() */

  memset( timeString, 0 , sizeof timeString ); /* entire content always is defined ! */

  ptm = gmtime( (const time_t *)&ltime ); //fill in time structure with ltime

  if( ptm )
  {
    strncpy(timeString, asctime( ptm ), sizeof(timeString)-1 );
  }

  return timeString;
}
```

If you use local static, your code is not reentrant/thread-safe.

Comment: @gordongekko: i do not completely understand what you are saying but for strncpy - "If the end of the source C string (which is signaled by a null-character) is found before num characters have been copied, destination is padded with zeros until a total of num characters have been written to it."

Comment: @Tommy: What he's getting at is that if the number of characters in the input string is equal to or larger than the size of the buffer then strncpy won't add a NUL terminator. The standard approach, I think, is to use `sizeof(buffer) - 1`, as shown in the answer's version of the code.

Answer (score 2):

Is this a Debug or Release build?

Could you use VC++ 2010 Express instead?  It is free, and unless you are using the "Visual" designer or MFC it is likely to be better.

I have not used VC++ 6.0 for a long time, but a number of other debuggers I have used seem to struggle with static variables, a simple solution is this:

```
static char timeString[STRLEN]; //hold string from asctime()
#if _DEBUG
char* timeStringDebugRef = timeString;
#endif
```

Then watch `timeStringDebugRef` instead of `timeString`.

---

[edit]

VC++ 6.0 supports a number of debug formats with options for both the linker and the compiler ([described here](http://www.debuginfo.com/articles/gendebuginfo.html#gendebuginfovc6)).  Make sure that you have it configured appropriately perhaps?

---